# How to draw lines from one to another point and update it without closing window in python

Tags: python, image-processing

Basically, like say what google maps does, I want to have a static background, that acts as a map, and then able to draw multiple lines signifying a path, and a marker telling where user is. Then I want to be able to update it to change where lines have been drawn as to change the path without closing the window where it's displayed

Comment: what have you tried? ... whar problem did you encounter?

Comment: I tried looking into matplotlib, but from all I saw I only could just for once show an array (I can just make values in the array), but to update it needs to be closed